# Fix org.apache.commons.fileupload.Fileupload.Setsizemax Error

Tags: nosuchmethoderror, apache-commons-fileupload, struts-1

I am getting the following error while trying to upload a file

> java.lang.Nosuchmethoderror
>
> Org.apache.commons.fileupload.Fileupload.Setsizemax

Does anybody have a solution regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error the method `Org.apache.commons.fileupload.Fileupload.Setsizemax` does not exist.
You can find an example about how to set the maximum file size in Struts 1.x on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767773/struts-1-x-file-upload-when-file-size-8mb).

Comment: Well, I have checked the jar file. This method does exist there

Comment: The link you have provided is about the size limit, the problem in my case is that whenever I submit, I get this error in server logs